# Output all names from an array in HTML

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to loop and get all arrays, every name with its own `<li>` element.

```html
<li>
#Foo
with all div and span inside here
</li>

<li>
#bar
with all div and span inside here
</li>

<li>
#moo
with all div and span inside here
</li>
```

```perl
use CGI::Pretty ":standard";

@names  = ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Moo');
my $str = join(" ",@names);

$data =  li (
           div({"class='inforno'"}, "<img src='inforno>'"),
           div({"class='inforno'"}, "<a href='#' class='inforno'>$str<
+/a>"),
           span({"class='inforno'"},  "<a href='#' class='inforno'>
                   Edit user </a>")

          );

     print "$data\n";
```

when I run I get only single `<li>` element with all names in the same `<li>`. I want to give each name its own `<li>` with all `<div>` and `<span>` elements inside in opening and closing `<li>` tags.

Comment: You might be better off using a dedicated templating module such as `HTML::Template` or `Template::Toolkit`.

Comment: @AhmedNumaan: Your edit made the English in the question substantially *worse*. Please don't vandalise Stack Overflow pages.

Comment: @Borodin I had to open up the dictionary to look for the meaning of "vandalize"(See spelling you wrote) that you used. Thanks for your advice anyways.

Comment: @Ahmed: “Vandalize” is American. “Vandalise” is English.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are using a very old copy of
[`CGI::Pretty`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Pretty),
your code produces this warning message when you run it

> CGI::Pretty is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future release. Please see https://github.com/leejo/CGI.pm/issues/162 for more information at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/CGI/Pretty.pm line 21.

It is important that you don't ignore warning messages: they are there to help you

You will also get three occurrences of this warning

> Odd number of elements in anonymous hash ...

That is because you are using `{"class='inforno'"}` which is the *wrong syntax* for an anonymous hash

Because CGI is deprecated, and because the HTML generation parts of the library are especially frowned on, it is best to use a templating system. One of the most popular templating systems is the
[`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit) module,
and this code shows you how to use it to achieve what you want

#### Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Template;

my @names  = qw/ Foo Bar Moo /;

my $template = Template->new;

binmode STDOUT;

$template->process('list.html', { list => \@names })
        or die $template->error;
```

#### list.html

```html
[% FOREACH name IN list %]
<li>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <img src='inforno'>
  </div>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>[% name %]</a>
  </div>
  <span class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Edit user</a>
  </span>
</li>
[% END %]
```

#### output

```html
<li>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <img src='inforno'>
  </div>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Foo</a>
  </div>
  <span class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Edit user</a>
  </span>
</li>

<li>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <img src='inforno'>
  </div>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Bar</a>
  </div>
  <span class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Edit user</a>
  </span>
</li>

<li>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <img src='inforno'>
  </div>
  <div class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Moo</a>
  </div>
  <span class='inforno'>
    <a href='#' class='inforno'>Edit user</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, and much more comprehensive than mine. It addresses all the issues with the original code. I salute you sir!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a `join`, you need to use a `foreach` loop and put the code that generates and prints the `<li>` inside the loop.

```
use CGI::Pretty ":standard";

@names  = ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Moo');

foreach $name (@names){
    $data =  li (
            div({"class='inforno'"}, "<img src='inforno>'"),
            div({"class='inforno'"}, "<a href='#' class='inforno'>$name</a>"),
            span({"class='inforno'"},  "<a href='#' class='inforno'>
                    Edit user </a>")

            );  

        print "$data\n";
}
```

Comment: This produces nine copies of the warning `Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at E:\Perl\source\pp.pl line 6.`

Comment: That's an error in the OP's code, not mine. The question wasn't about fixing warnings or any other problems, it was about how to write a loop. Please downvote the OP's question, not this answer.

Comment: And you think it's okay to post answers containing incorrect Perl code, just because the OP didn't ask about those issues?

Comment: @Borodin yes I do think it's completely okay to post an answer containing 'incorrect' Perl code because I was quoting the OP's code and answering one specific question. It wouldn't make sense to change multiple aspects of the code, that would just be confusing.

Comment: @Will: I appreciate your comment on my answer: thank you. But I wonder that you rate it at all when you say *"It wouldn't make sense to change multiple aspects of the code, that would just be confusing"*. There is no trace of the original code in my answer at all!

Comment: @Borodin Yours is the answer to a different question "Could you fix my code?", which is obviously very useful to the OP. I defend my answer as literally correct, while yours serves a wider purpose.